# How to pass environment variable to Jenkins Remote API when submitting job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli, jenkins-api

I have a declarative pipeline job (this is *not* multi-branch pipeline job using `Jenkinsfile`) without parameters but some stages are conditional based on value in environment variable:

```
stage('deploy-release') {
    when {
        environment name: 'GIT_BRANCH', value: 'master'
    }
    steps {
        sh "mvn deploy:deploy-file -B -DpomFile=pom.xml -Dfile=target/example.jar -DrepositoryId=maven-releases -Durl=${NEXUS_URL}/repository/maven-releases/"
    }
}
```

I want to trigger the job from external system but I need to pass correct value of given environment variable. Is there some way how to do that via Jenkins Remote API?

Answer (score 0):

For passing value of given environment variable, you need to define parameters with the exact same name as that of environment variable for your job by selecting "This build is parameterized".

You can refer [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)